# Create a JavaScript array of objects group and sum items

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have an array of company reviews like below, and from that, I am trying to generate three new arrays. I have managed to create two arrays with sums but the last one(rating filter) is where I got stuck, want to create an array for the ratings with 5 items like 1 star, 2 stars, and so on.

```
const reviews = [
   {
        designation_id: 544,
        designation: 'Software Developer',
        department_id: 18,
        department: 'IT & Information Security',
        overall_rating: 4
    },
    {
        designation_id: 592,
        designation: 'UI Designer',
        department_id: 37,
        department: 'UX, Design & Architecture',
        overall_rating: 5
    },
    {
        designation_id: 544,
        designation: 'Software Developer',
        department_id: 18,
        department: 'IT & Information Security',
        overall_rating: 3
    }
]
```

The **desired Output**:

```
const ratingFilter = [
    {count: 2, name: '1 Star'}, 
    {count: 1, name: '2 Stars'},
    {count: 3, name: '3 Stars'},
    {count: 1, name: '4 Stars'},
    {count: 2, name: '5 Stars'}, 
]
```

This is what I have done so far:

```
const departmentFilters = [];
const designationFilters = [];

arr.reduce((accu: { [key: string]: any }, curr) => {
    const departmentKey = curr.department
        .split(' ')
        .join('_')
        .toLowerCase();

    const designationKey = curr.designation
        .split(' ')
        .join('_')
        .toLowerCase();

    //departments filters
    if (!accu[departmentKey]) {
        accu[departmentKey] = {
            count: 1,
            name: curr.department,
            id: curr.department_id
        };
            departmentFilters.push(accu[departmentKey]);
        } else {
            accu[departmentKey].count++;
        }

        //desinations filters
        if (!accu[designationKey]) {
            accu[designationKey] = {
                count: 1,
                name: curr.designation,
                id: curr.designation_id
            };
            designationFilters.push(accu[designationKey]);
        } else {
            accu[designationKey].count++;
        }

        return accu;
}, Object.create(null));
```

Comment: The desired output doesn't look like it follows from the input. Do you mean you want `ratingFilter` to equal `{count: 0, name: '1 Star'}, {count: 0, name: '2 Star'}, {count: 0, name: '3 Star'}, {count: 2, name: '4 Star'}, {count: 1, name: '5 Star'}`?

Comment: what is `arr` in what you have done so far? Why doesn't what you've done so far even run? Oh, I see, it's TYPEscript - you never mentioned that - what is `ratingFilter`

Comment: @RockySims, Yes, I have the added entire output. But I am getting trouble in rating filter

Comment: your code has no such variable, that's why it's not output

Comment: @JaromandaX, What variable you are asking?

Comment: `ratingFilter` ... in your desired output, you've done nothing to create it

Comment: @JaromandaX, I no confused about how I am going to create the last array. I have managed to create the first two. That is why i have asked for help

Comment: Oh, I thought the code you posted was your attempt at solving your issue, which looked odd admittedly - didn't realise you didn't even try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have come up with, as the rating will always be a round number and it will be from 1 to 5. I don't if this is the best way to do it. If there is a better way please suggest it.

```js
const reviews = [
   {
        designation_id: 544,
        designation: 'Software Developer',
        department_id: 18,
        department: 'IT & Information Security',
        overall_rating: 4
    },
    {
        designation_id: 592,
        designation: 'UI Designer',
        department_id: 37,
        department: 'UX, Design & Architecture',
        overall_rating: 5
    },
    {
        designation_id: 544,
        designation: 'Software Developer',
        department_id: 18,
        department: 'IT & Information Security',
        overall_rating: 3
    }
];
const departmentFilters = [];
const designationFilters = [];
const ratingFilter = Array.from(
  { length: 5 },
  (value, index) => {
     index = index + 1;
     return {
        count: 0,
        id: index,
        name: `${index} Star`,
     };
  },
);
    
reviews.reduce((accu, curr) => {
    const departmentKey = curr.department
        .split(' ')
        .join('_')
        .toLowerCase();

    const designationKey = curr.designation
        .split(' ')
        .join('_')
        .toLowerCase();

    //departments filters
    if (!accu[departmentKey]) {
        accu[departmentKey] = {
            count: 1,
            name: curr.department,
            id: curr.department_id
        };
            departmentFilters.push(accu[departmentKey]);
        } else {
            accu[departmentKey].count++;
        }

        //desinations filters
        if (!accu[designationKey]) {
            accu[designationKey] = {
                count: 1,
                name: curr.designation,
                id: curr.designation_id
            };
            designationFilters.push(accu[designationKey]);
        } else {
            accu[designationKey].count++;
        }

        //rating filter count
        if (curr.overall_rating > 0) {
            const index = curr.overall_rating - 1;
            ratingFilter[index].count++;
        }

        return accu;
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(ratingFilter);
console.log(departmentFilters);
console.log(designationFilters);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I'd do it (assuming I'm understanding your question correctly).

```js
const reviews = [{
    designation_id: 544,
    designation: 'Software Developer',
    department_id: 18,
    department: 'IT & Information Security',
    overall_rating: 4
}, {
    designation_id: 592,
    designation: 'UI Designer',
    department_id: 37,
    department: 'UX, Design & Architecture',
    overall_rating: 5
}, {
    designation_id: 544,
    designation: 'Software Developer',
    department_id: 18,
    department: 'IT & Information Security',
    overall_rating: 3.8
}];

const reviewCountByOverallRating = {};
for (let review of reviews) {
    const overallRating = review.overall_rating; //or perhaps Math.round(review.overall_rating) if you want whole numbers only
    reviewCountByOverallRating[overallRating] = reviewCountByOverallRating[overallRating] || 0;
    reviewCountByOverallRating[overallRating]++;
}

const ratingFilter = [];
for (let overallRating in reviewCountByOverallRating) {
    const reviewCount = reviewCountByOverallRating[overallRating];
    ratingFilter.push({
        count: reviewCount,
        name: `${overallRating} Star${overallRating === 1 ? '' : 's'}`
    });
}

console.log(ratingFilter);
```

Comment: I can have a large number of data, can we reduce the number of loops

Comment: There is no way to avoid looping over all the `reviews` (and `reviewCountByOverallRating` will remain small even for a huge number of `reviews`) so I think reducing the number of loops is not needed. How many reviews do you expect to have?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method.

Live Demo **:**

```js
const reviews = [{
    designation_id: 544,
    designation: 'Software Developer',
    department_id: 18,
    department: 'IT & Information Security',
    overall_rating: 4
}, {
    designation_id: 592,
    designation: 'UI Designer',
    department_id: 37,
    department: 'UX, Design & Architecture',
    overall_rating: 5
}, {
    designation_id: 544,
    designation: 'Software Developer',
    department_id: 18,
    department: 'IT & Information Security',
    overall_rating: 3.8
}];

let res = reviews.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (!curr.count) curr.count = 1
  if (!acc.some(({ rating }) => rating == curr.overall_rating)) {
    acc.push({
        rating: curr.overall_rating,
      count: curr.count
    });
  } else {
    acc.find(({ rating }) => rating == curr.overall_rating).count++;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```